# Why Do My Webfonts Not Show On Windows Machines and iPhone?

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

I have designed a very basic holding page at [www.tomrankinmusic.com](http://www.tomrankinmusic.com)

I have embedded Webfonts into the page and checked them in the latest Firefox, Safari and Chrome on Mac OSX Lion 10.7.4 where they show correctly, however they do not show in Chrome and IE6 on Windows XP Pro and default to Times New Roman.

What is the reason for this and how can I rectify it?

As an additional question, I understand that iPhone only recognises SVG fonts and I didn't get access to the SVG font when purchasing on myfonts.com.  Is there any other way I can display webfonts on Safari Mobile?

Also, IE6 displays the large logo on the page with a grey background - I'm not even sure whether I should be worried about IE6 performance but, you know the web surfing public.

Comment: u have this font from google fonts?

Comment: No.  I bought my font from myfonts.com, but I am using a Google Font for main body text.  This however is not in use on this webpage

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HI now convert your font this ***[site](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)***  and apply than your page

Comment: I didn't think I needed to use that.  I'm also not sure if I am able to do that as per the Terms and Conditions of my purchase.  But I will check this and see if this works

Answer (score 1):

U can also use this converter, if FS will be have problems http://fontface.codeandmore.com/